# Python selenium Element not clickable since another element obscures it

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following code. There is a problem in the line with:

```
timePicker = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="time hasTimepicker"]')
```

It raises this exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <input id="tp1594226550595" class="time hasTimepicker" type="text"> is not clickable at point (753,293) because another element <rect class="highcharts-background"> obscures it
```

I have already tried solutions which use 'wait', but there is a timeout exception. It seems the obstruction is permanent. I have also tried ActionChains, but it's not working either.

The element I am trying to click on is in this image:

[image]

The graph is the element obscuring the time picker at the top:
[image]

```
from time import sleep, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import \
    NoSuchElementException, \
    ElementClickInterceptedException, \
    ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:/Users/USER/Documents/temp")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")

print('opening browser')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path='C:/Users/USER/Documents/Python Workspace/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe',
    firefox_profile=fp
)
print('opening link')
browser.get('https://webtrader.binary.com/v2.2.8/main.html#historical-data')

def close_popup():
    entrytime = time()
    try:
        currenttime = time()
        if currenttime - entrytime >= 10:
            return
        close1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/button/span[1]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sleep(2)
        close_popup()

    try:
        currenttime = time()
        if currenttime - entrytime >= 10:
            return
        click_element(close1)
    except UnboundLocalError:
        currenttime = time()
        if currenttime - entrytime >= 10:
            return
        sleep(2)
        close_popup()


def click_element(element):
    entrytime = time()
    try:
        currenttime = time()
        if currenttime - entrytime >= 10:
            return
        element.click()
        sleep(2)
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        currenttime = time()
        if currenttime - entrytime >= 10:
            return
        sleep(2)
        click_element(element)
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        currenttime = time()
        if currenttime - entrytime >= 10:
            return
        sleep(2)
        click_element(element)


def resources():
    try:
        global res
        res = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Resources')
        res.click()
        sleep(2)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        resources()

print('accessing Resources')
resources()

print()
#
#
def historical_data():
    global res
    try:
        hd = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Historical Data')
        sleep(2)
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        sleep(2)
        historical_data()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sleep(2)
        res.click()
        historical_data()
    try:
        hd.click()
        sleep(2)
    except UnboundLocalError:
        sleep(2)
        historical_data()
    # hd.click()
    # sleep(2)


print('accessing Historical data')
historical_data()

maxWindow = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div/a[3]/span')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', maxWindow)
sleep(2)

print('setting data type to 1 Tick')

while True:
    try:
        dt = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sleep(2)

dt.click()
sleep(2)

tick = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span')
tick.click()
sleep(2)
#
while True:
    try:
        timePicker = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="time hasTimepicker"]')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sleep(2)

timePicker.click()
```

Comment: If the intercepting element is hiding the actual element, then try sending the click to the intercepting element. It is not ideal, but does the work.

Comment: @PaulO. insulting other users is a sure fire way to ensure you get downvoted even more, and no one helps you. If you know what is blocking it, then it is best to find a way to remove it (either clicking outside the pop up box, or if the thing obscuring it has an accept/cancel button that will enable it to go away. If those don't work, you may try to add a wait period, to 1) enable to pop or whatever hiding it to load up, and 2) give it time to go away once you click on it to remove it. Finally, it might be easier to add a screenshot (driver.screenshot in the part you get the error)

Comment: @samman have you tried out my code?

Comment: No, I don't use firefox. Which is why it was a comment, and not an answer. If you wish, you may upload a screenshot of the webpage, thus I can see what/where the timer is and what is obstructing it.

Comment: @samman i have attached the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
while True:
    try:
        timePicker = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[4]/input[2]')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sleep(2)

timePicker.click()
```

Additionally, you import WebDriverWait, but don't use it. Try this, replace:

```
while True:
    try:
        dt = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sleep(2)

dt.click()
sleep(2)

tick = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span')
tick.click()
sleep(2)
#
while True:
    try:
        timePicker = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="time hasTimepicker"]')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sleep(2)

timePicker.click()
```

with this:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span'))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[8]/div[4]/input[2]'))).click()
```

You'll immediately notice its significantly faster, and cleaner. I'd replace all those while,try, and time.sleep() with WebDriverWait.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! it worked perfectly. If you have time, could you please recommend a book or website where you learnt that. I will be working with selenium for several weeks to come.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any books. I use the docs for all my questions: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html